# Post form but I can not get more than one data

Tags: javascript

I used this form and I have 3 datas and I posted them with form like this:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", "/app/" + @appId + "/volumes/" + obj.data("rowid") + "/scheduledPublish");

var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "dateval");
hiddenField.setAttribute("value", dateval);
form.appendChild(hiddenField);

var hiddenField2 = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField2.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
hiddenField2.setAttribute("name", "hourval");
hiddenField2.setAttribute("value", hourval);
form.appendChild(hiddenField2);

var hiddenField3 = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField3.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
hiddenField3.setAttribute("name", "minuteval");
hiddenField3.setAttribute("value", minuteval);
form.appendChild(hiddenField3);

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

how can I get these like method:

```
public static Result deleteVolume(Long dateval, Long appId) {
}
```

Comment: please provide more information. Are you using any PHP framework ?

Comment: There's no visibility modifier nor types in JS. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using modal framework. I want to post datas from my html file to get my java file. I have 3 datas in html named dateval, hourval and minuteval. I posted with this form dateval, hourval and minuteval but I don't know how I get them from java with method public static Result FUU(Log ??, Long ???){}

Comment: in method use this to get for one value {Form<String> form = form(String.class).bindFromRequest();}

Answer (score 0):

I solved. I got the form datas from javascript to java like

```
    form.data().get("name value")
```